# Active Tab not staying highlighted with BottomNavigationBar (flips on then back off)

Tags: dart, flutter

I am building a flutter app with several different files so I can piece them together as needed.  One of the separate files builds out a BottomNavigationBar. The other files build out the separate pages that the BottomNavigationBar will link to. Navigation works fine, but every time I change screens, the color of the BottomNavigationBar (which should be highlighting the screen that is currently active) is snapping back to the first tab. I am certain the reason for this is that when I click on the BottomNavigationBar, it appropriately routes me to the next view (and in fact I see the new tab highlighted on the old view before going to the next one) and then once on the new page, BottomNavigationBar is being called again, where I am establishing that it start at its home point (the first tab) until further notice.  Here is the code for the BottomNavigationBar file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'profile.dart';
import 'search.dart';
import 'favorites.dart';
import 'featured.dart';

class NavBar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  NavBarState createState() => NavBarState();
}

 class NavBarState extends State<NavBar>{

 int currentTab = 0;

  FeaturedScreen one;
  SearchScreen two;
  FavoritesScreen three;
  ProfileScreen four;
  List<Widget> pages;
  Widget currentPage;

  @override
  void initState() {
    one = FeaturedScreen();
    two = SearchScreen();
    three = FavoritesScreen();
    four = ProfileScreen();

    pages = [one, two, three, four];

    super.initState();
  } 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomNavigationBar( 
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      currentIndex: currentTab,
      fixedColor: new Color(0xffffffff).withOpacity(0.5), 
      onTap: (int index) {
        setState((){
          currentTab = index;
          currentPage = pages[index];
        });
        Navigator.push(
          context, 
          new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => currentPage)
        );
      },
      items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[ 
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: currentTab==0?Icon( 
            Icons.apps,
            color: Color(0xff70E0EF),
            size: 35.0,
           ):Icon(
            Icons.apps,
            color: Colors.black,
            size: 35.0,
          ),
          title: Text(
            'Collections',
            style: new TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 0.0,
              height: 0.0,
            ),
          ), 
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: currentTab==1?Icon(
            Icons.search,
            color: Color(0xff70E0EF),
            size: 35.0,
          ):Icon(
            Icons.search,
            color: Colors.black,
            size: 35.0,
          ),
          title: Text(
            'Search',
            style: new TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 0.0,
              height: 0.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: currentTab==2?Icon(
            Icons.favorite,
            color: Color(0xff70E0EF),
            size: 35.0,
          ):Icon(
            Icons.favorite,
            color: Colors.black,
            size: 35.0,
          ),
          title: Text(
            'Favorites',
            style: new TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 0.0,
              height: 0.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: currentTab==3?Icon(
            Icons.person,
            color: Color(0xff70E0EF),
            size: 35.0,
          ):Icon(
            Icons.person,
            color: Colors.black,
            size: 35.0,
          ), 
          title: Text(
            'Profile',
            style: new TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 0.0,
              height: 0.0,
            ),
          ),           
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Each of the four items will load a page that, for now, looks more or less exactly like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'navbar.dart';

class FeaturedScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Featured(),
      bottomNavigationBar: NavBar(),
    );
  }
}

class Featured extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  FeaturedState createState() => FeaturedState();
}

class FeaturedState extends State<Featured>{

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold( 
      body: new Stack(
        fit: StackFit.passthrough,
        children: [
          new Container(
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              image: new DecorationImage(
                image: new AssetImage('assets/FeaturedBG.png'),
                fit: BoxFit.cover
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How can I make it so that BottomNavigationBar activates correctly per active page?

P.S. Sorry if this was a confusing question.  Happy to make a gif of what's happening on request.

Comment: It looks like each page has it's own bottom nav bar, so navigating to any new page will reset the state to whatever it was initially.

Comment: Yeah, I think you’re right about that.  I’m just not sure how to get it to recognize that a change has happened upon reload?  Or am I somehow over complicating things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example code you have posted, each page is getting a new BottomNavigationBar.  So when you navigate to it, it will always begin at the initial state.  To avoid this problem, you should structure your pages so that there is a single bottom navigation bar that they all share, instead of using the router.  You will also need to remove the Scaffold and nav bar from each page.

```
class MyScreens extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyScreensState createState() => new MyScreensState();
}

class MyScreensState extends State<MyScreens> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: _pages[currentTab], // <- change the widget here
      navBar: new BottomNavigationBar( /* ... */),
    );
  }
}
```

For more ideas on how to structure a bottom nav bar, check out the example code in the [flutter gallery](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/material/bottom_navigation_demo.dart).

Comment: That's it!  Thanks for the assist!

Comment: Examples now here https://github.com/flutter/gallery/blob/master/lib/demos/material/bottom_navigation_demo.dart